# LinkedList issue printing and deleting

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, nodes, circular-list

Ok so I've been debating on whether or not to ask and keep this question up to see if I can get some answers. I have fixed most of the bugs but I'm having a huge issue with this LinkedList. Right now it keeps deleting all my Nodes behind the very first one and displays all but the last Node. I can't seem to figure out where my issues are. I have been using the debug in jgrasp to help but it hasn't helped too much

I have included the two files that I'm working on for anyone who wants to run it and see what happens themselves

The file input is a text file that will have something similar to this:

```
 1,10
 5,16
 2,7
 4,12
 3,19
 6,25
 9,13
 7,21
 8,4
```

It will take an int as well that will represent a time. I have been
 using 5

This is my main file:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Test_RoundRobin{

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    LinkedList list=new LinkedList();
    String file=args[0];
    int cpuTime=Integer.parseInt(args[1]);

    Scanner fin=new Scanner(new FileReader(file));
    String pattern=",";
    fin.useDelimiter(pattern);
    while(fin.hasNext()){
        String s=fin.nextLine();
        String[] array=s.split(pattern);
        int pid=Integer.parseInt(array[0]);
        int time=Integer.parseInt(array[1]);
        list.add(pid, time);
    }
    fin.close();
    System.out.println(list);
    list.sortList();
    System.out.println(list);
    int count=1;
    while(list.size!=0){
        list.timeSlice(cpuTime);
        System.out.println("Run " + count + ": " + list);
        count++;
    }
    System.out.println(list);
}
}
```

This is the LinkedList file that I have: I'm using a dummy head node and it is a circular singly linked list.

```
public class LinkedList{
private class Node{
    private int pid;
    private int time;
    private Node next;

    public Node(int pid, int time){
        this.pid=pid;
        this.time=time;
    }
}//end Node

int size;
Node head;

public void add(int pid, int time) {
    Node curr=head;
    Node newNode=new Node(pid, time);
    //empty list
    if(head==null){
        head=newNode;
        newNode.next=head;
    }//end if
    else{
        while(curr.next!=head){
            curr=curr.next;
        }//end while
        curr.next=newNode;
        newNode.next=head;
    }//end else
    size++;
}//end add

public void delete(Node curr){
    if(size==0){
        return;
    }
    else if(head==curr){
        head=curr.next;
    }
    else{
        Node prev=find(curr);
        prev.next=curr.next;
    }
    size--;
}

public Node find(Node curr){
    for(Node prev=head; prev.next!=curr; prev=prev.next){
        return prev;
    }
    return curr;
}

public void sortList(){
    Node position;  // Position to fill...
    Node start;            // Where to start looking for the smallest...

    if(size>=0){
        for(position=head; position.next!=head; position=position.next){
            Node smallest=position;

            for(start=position.next; start!=head; start=start.next){
                if (start.pid<smallest.pid){
                    smallest = start;
                }//end if
            }//end for
            int tempPID=position.pid;
            int tempTime=position.time;
            position.pid=smallest.pid;
            position.time=smallest.time;
            smallest.pid=tempPID;
            smallest.time=tempTime;
        }//end for
    }//end if
}//end sortList

public void timeSlice(int cpuTime){
    for(Node curr=head; curr.next!=head; curr=curr.next){
        curr.time=curr.time-cpuTime;
        System.out.print("<" + curr.pid + ", " + curr.time +">" + " ");
        //if the time remaining <= 0 then remove the node
        if(curr.time<=0){
            System.out.println("Process " + curr.pid + " has finished, and is now being terminated");
            delete(curr);
        }
    }
}

public String toString(){
    String s="";
    for(Node curr=head; curr.next!=head; curr=curr.next)
        s=s+"<"+curr.pid+", "+curr.time+"> ";

    return s;
}
}
```

Thanks in advance, It is greatly appreciated.

Comment: i apologize if you have seen this multiple times. i keep being indecisive and pulling it down

Answer (score 1):

First off, you aren't using a dummy node like you said you are. If the list contains only a single node, it will never actually be deleted, since `head.next` is just `head` again. This also puts the list in an inconsistent state where `size` is 0 but it still has a node.

`find` will give incorrect results if you're looking for a node that's not in the list. You should probably detect this and throw an exception.

Comment: i thought if you have head.next pointing to head that would be a dummy head node.

Comment: It would be, expect that you're using the "dummy" to store real data, and you don't have one in your empty list. The real problem is that your `LinkedList` uses the default constructor.

Comment: Ok, well then I will have to fix that. That might explain why when I debug in jgrasp I get a Node full of the other Nodes

Comment: It might help if you work out some examples on paper to figure out exactly what you want your list to do. You seem a bit confused about the design.

Comment: I'm getting started on drawing some stuff out. The biggest thing that is confusing me is having two values in the Node

Comment: in a get/set constructor how would you do it for 2 values. Would you create a set/get for each value or do it all in one? I'm thinking separate

Comment: What is a "get/set constructor"? Anyway, you'll need a way to distinguish the dummy node from the legitimate nodes.

Comment: We have been taught to use a get/set constructor that will take something like `setTime(int time){this.time=time;} and get which would call it getTime{return time;}`

Comment: Getters and setters are nothing to do with constructors (and IMO are usually bad practice, though they're idiomatic in Java). Especially in the case of an internal class like this, you might as well just expose the fields.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28624/discussion-between-kevorski-and-antimony)